# PHP Global variable not being imported into session handler

Tags: php, adodb-php

I'm using ADOdb. For some reason, the actual `$db` is not getting imported in the 'write' function.

The function is intended to import the `$db`'s actual value. Instead, it's assigning an empty value to `$db`:

```
<?php
// load ADODB class
include(DIR_WS_CLASSES . "adodb5/adodb.inc.php");

$db = NewADOConnection(DB_TYPE);
$db->Connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);


class SessionManager {
    var $life_time;

    function SessionManager(){
        global $db;
        // Read the maxlifetime setting from PHP
        $this->life_time = get_cfg_var("session.gc_maxlifetime");

        // Register this object as the session handler
        session_set_save_handler(array(&$this, "open"), 
                                array(&$this, "close"), 
                                array(&$this, "read"), 
                                array(&$this, "write"), 
                                array(&$this, "destroy"), 
                                array(&$this, "gc"));
    }

    function open($save_path, $session_name){
        global $sess_save_path;
        global $db;

        $sess_save_path = $save_path;

        return true;
    }

    function close(){
        global $db;
        return true;
    }

    function read($id){
        global $db;
        // Set empty result
        $data = '';

        // Fetch session data from the selected database
        $time = time();
        $newid = $db->qstr($id, get_magic_quotes_gpc());

        $sql = "SELECT session_data 
                FROM sessions 
                WHERE session_id = $newid 
                AND expires > $time";

        $rs = $db->Execute($sql) or die($db->ErrorMsg());
        $a = $rs->RecordCount();

        if($a > 0){
            $data = $rs->fields['session_data'];
        }

        return $data;
    }

    function write($id, $data){
        global $db;
        // Build query                
        $time = time() + $this->life_time;
        $newid = $db->qstr($id, get_magic_quotes_gpc());
        $newdata = $db->qstr($data, get_magic_quotes_gpc());
        $sql = "REPLACE sessions
                (session_id, session_data, expires) 
                VALUES($newid, $newdata, $time)";

        $rs = $db->Execute($sql) or die($db->ErrorMsg());

        return TRUE;
    }

    function destroy($id){
        global $db;
        // Build query
        $newid = $db->qstr($id, get_magic_quotes_gpc());
        $sql = "DELETE FROM sessions 
                WHERE session_id = $newid";

        $db->Execute($sql) or die($db->ErrorMsg());

        return TRUE;
    }

    function gc(){
    // Garbage Collection
        global $db;
        // Build DELETE query.  Delete all records that passed expiration time
        $sql = "DELETE FROM sessions 
                WHERE expires < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()";

        $db->Execute($sql) or die($db->ErrorMsg());

        // Always return TRUE
        return true;
    }
}


// initialize session
$sess = new SessionManager();
session_start();
?>
```

Why is  the actual `$db` not imported in the 'write' function?

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: How do you know $db is empty? What error message are you getting? The posted code works fine, when fleshed out. Please post a minimal test case. You can also try a debugger (such as Eclipse+PDT+XDEBUG) to track down what's happening. Note that globals are evil; a better solution would be to add a `$db` member to the object `write` is a method of.

Comment: Can you tell us what error are you getting. Is it saying that some function called on undefined object. Or something else. I totally believe that you are assigning $db something else somewhere OR you are closing the connection. Something like that. Tell us about the error that you are getting.

Comment: I am receiving Fatal error: Call to a member function qstr() on a non-object in E:\applications\myfurni\webroot\includes\classes\sessions\sessions.php on line 64

Comment: Nirmal see my 2nd answer below. Check it in your code. I am sure it will solve your problem.

Comment: As far as I know session_start(); should be at the top of the page.

Comment: @vyger: This whole handler is for session handling. That is, to tell PHP what it should do when session_start is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDITED FOR THOSE WHO DIDN'T FOLLOW THE COMMENTS ;)

"As of PHP 5.0.5 the write and close handlers are called after object destruction and therefore cannot use objects or throw exceptions. The object destructors can however use sessions. It is possible to call session_write_close() from the destructor to solve this chicken and egg problem"

So the idea is to have a destructor like this:

```
function __destruct() {
    session_write_close();
}
```

So that objects can be used in the write & close handlers.

Then, for safety, to re-instantiate $db in write & close because the global $db destructor may very well be called before the SessionHandler one.

Comment: Maybe you should put a little more of you code so we can have some context.

Comment: You forgot "global $db;" in the write method.

Comment: But I have hard time understanding your logic... why isn't $db a member of your class?

Comment: No. I wrongly posted my latest trial. Now I have corrected the code sample. Please have a look and see if you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. It's very possible the global $db variable is garbage collected before the session is closed/saved. You should read the doc regarding the session custom handlers carefully. You may need to recreate the db connection at a certain point.

Comment: Oh my God, somehow I missed it! Now I have assigned $db as a member of class and everything works fine. Thank you. That was a nice catch!

Comment: No.. assigning as member doesn't work. The page was cached it seems.

Comment: @Juilan: I am not really sure about why you did.

global $db;
$db=& new MyClass();

If you are creating a new object, then why to import it by using global keyword.

Comment: @Krishna: the global $db I marked here was to be put before the global declaration. See, if you include a php file and it happens to end up in a function scope, the $db will never be global, hence the use of global $db before the assignment. Believe me, I had the issue and I thought it may have been Nirmal's one... but I was mistaken ;)

Comment: @Nirmal: yes, I'm almost certain globals have been cleansed when the write handler is called. A good solution would be to have $db be a member of the class.

Comment: @Nirmal: I had skipped your comments... put the code with $db as an approach somewhere... because it should work. I'd like to review it.

Comment: @Nirmal: with $db as a member... jeez, my writing is spacey Oo

Comment: @Nirmal: look in my post now and try it.

Comment: @Nirmal: public static $db; does nothing unless you use it as SessionManager::$db ;) Have you tried the code I put into my post?

Comment: Oh, OK. I tried yours but the $db variable in all the functions are failing. I am getting an undefined error.

Comment: Wait... you do instance the SessionManager at one point?

Anyway, are you sure you can give methods as session handlers?

Comment: AHA! The PHP doc has something interesting: "As of PHP 5.0.5 the write and close handlers are called after object destruction and therefore cannot use objects or throw exceptions. The object destructors can however use sessions.

It is possible to call session_write_close() from the destructor to solve this chicken and egg problem."

Comment: @Nirmal: so basically, revert to your original code but add a destructor to SessionManager that calls session_write_close(). That way, you'll be able to use objects in your handlers before object destruction. Hopefully, the SessionManager will be destroyed before the $db object but it would be safer to create a new ADOConnection in write and close just to be safe.

Comment: Since I am new to PHP classes, it would be nice if you can show me how to add a destructor. Thank you.

Comment: "function __destruct() { session_write_close(); }" but remember, chances are the $db object would have been destroyed first, so make a new one in write & close. Session handlers are tricky as hell, you're crazy to start with that in PHP ;)

Comment: OK. I tried destructor but still the problem persists. I am reverting to the original code with $db intialized again. Whoever you are, thank you for your patience and passion to help. Have a great day!

Comment: I wish you good luck. Custom session handling in php is a hell of a sport ;)

Comment: @Nirmal: oh, and you have *2* underscores in front of destruct (just in case, I made the error often in the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

Either you don't assign `$db` as global or you assign it an empty value.

Comment: I didn't want to assign empty value to $db.
The global $db is assigning empty value instead of importing the original value.

Comment: `global $db` isn't assigning anything. It basically imports `$db` into local namespace. So the question is whether you did assign anything to `$db` in global namespace (either outside of all functions or inside the function with `global $db` declaration.

Comment: Yes, a class is assigned to $db outside all functions and it occurs near the start of the page.

Comment: This code is part of the session handler function I am writing for saving into the database. Now I have a doubt whether the writing of session occurs inside or outside the scripting thread.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$db` after assignment? The thing is, every newbie suspects that it's his runtime environment that is at fault (we all do that), but almost always it is not, so check your flow and syntax.

Comment: It  may be executed before you get to assign your `$db`.

Comment: Consider initialilzinig `$db` in the `open` part of the handler?

Comment: Try tracing your assignment and use and see what happens first.

Comment: and make sure you have `global $db` in your `open` handler if you assign it there.

Comment: Now I solved the issue by redeclaring the class to $db:
$db = NewADOConnection(DB_TYPE);
$db->Connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

But why can't I import it to the local namespace? Definitely the session is written within the scripting scope because the defined variable are properly being applied.

Comment: I think it's the order of execution that bites you.

Comment: I have posted the whole class. Maybe you can help in finding out if any problem exists. Thanks!

Comment: The important bit is whether you initialize `$db` before or after use. The code posted has no `$db` initialization so it's hard to tell. I'm pretty sure if you put it into your `open()` memeber it will work.

Comment: $db is initialized before calling this function.

Comment: before calling *which* function? ;-)

Comment: Sorry. Before using the class. :-)

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Try looking up the `$GLOBALS['db']` at various points of execution...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP expert but maybe you're overwriting it. Try an echo of $db before and after

global $db;

And: are you sure you assigned anything to $db (before looking to its value inside the function)?

Comment: I tried that and found no overwriting occuring at any place.
A class is assigned to $db at the top of the page. So, I am very sure there is a preset value for the variable. Moreover, global $db is working in other functions!

Answer (score 0):

Try var_dump on $db outside and inside the function.

Comment: When I do var_dump outside the function, it's showing the intended values.
If inside before using global, it gives an undefined variable error.
If after the global, it shows empty value.

Answer (score 0):

You dont seem initialise `$db` anywhere in the above code.

I would expect to see a `$db = new ADO("myserver,mydb,user,password")` call somewhere 
in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try these 2 things:

1. Assign

   ```
   $GLOBALS['db']=...;
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   $db=...;
   ```

   in your global script. Then reference it in your function as `$db=$GLOBALS['db'];`.

   **Reason**: It's a possibility that you are assigning `$db` in some place which is not global.
2. Make it as private property of your class. Provide a getter, but not the setter. Instead set it from your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure what is the problem.
See your code will work fine when this file was included in global scope.
But consider this:

```
$a=1;
function displaya()
{
    global $a;
    var_dump($a);
}
```

When you run this file you will see `int(1)` as the output.

But consider another file:

```
function abc()
{
include("above-stated-file.php");
displaya();
}

abc();
```

Now it will display `NULL`.

The reason is that in second file. Your first file was included in a local context, not the global one. Thats why `global $a` doesn't work.

Change it to:

```
$GLOBALS['a']=....;
```

and when you use it: `$a=$GLOBALS['a'];`

Comment: I tried it, but still Iget an error Notice: Undefined index: db in E:\applications\myfurni\webroot\includes\classes\sessions\sessions.php on line 59

Comment: I assigned it like this: $GLOBALS['db'] = NewADOConnection(DB_TYPE);