# Unexpected "mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in"

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while now. I am getting an unexpected error namely "mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in"

Below is the sample code referring to where this error is happening.

```
function tep_db_input($string, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;

    return mysqli_real_escape_string($$link, $string);
}
```

The mysqli object is being made in this piece of code.

```
function tep_db_connect($server = DB_SERVER, $username = DB_SERVER_USERNAME, $password = DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, $database = DB_DATABASE, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;

    if (USE_PCONNECT == 'true') {
      $server = 'p:' . $server;
    }

    $$link = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

    if ( !mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
      mysqli_set_charset($$link, 'utf8');
    } 

    return $$link;
}
```

The rest of the mysqli functions like this are all in the same file. This file gets included at the start of the page. Like this.

```
// make a connection to the database... now
tep_db_connect() or die('Unable to connect to database server!');
```

A little bit of background to this whole situation. It's an OsCommerce webshop a really old version at that, recently we have decided to migrate from PHP 5.3 to 5.6 forcing us to use the new mysqli_* extension instead of mysql_*.
Ever since I have been getting multiple errors pertaining to the issue where the object won't work within another function, while I'm still using global  to get it wihin the scope. I've done a var_dump right before the mysqli_real_escape_string() is being called and get a proper mysqli object back.

Currently this version of the website is not live so I'm accessing it via editing the hosts file. I'm not sure if this is influencing any behaviour but I thought any info added to the story could help.

```
function tep_db_input($string, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;
    var_dump($$link);

    return mysqli_real_escape_string($$link, $string);
}
```

Results

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(161) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(14) "5.5.41-MariaDB" ["server_version"]=> int(50541) ["stat"]=> string(149) "Uptime: 2338516 Threads: 8 Questions: 166189149 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 1664692 Flush tables: 2 Open tables: 400 Queries per second avg: 71.066" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(2568661) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }
```

Yet I'm still getting the error saying there is null given in the function which makes no sense to me since there clearly is something in the variable as the var_dump shows.

I'm well aware that using global in combination with mysqli isn't the best practice so please do not try to correct me on that. I'm simply looking for the cause why my object dissapears right before the function is called.

My question here is why is the object not being recognized by the function yet the var_dump shows it's a mysqli object.

Many thanks for taking the time to read through all of this and I hope anyone can be of help.

EDIT1:
Just to double check the answer given by @xXDarioXx
I did two var_dumps of the variable but in different forms. Here is the code.

```
echo $string;
echo '<br/>';
var_dump($db_link);
echo '<br/>';
echo '<br/>';
var_dump($$link);
echo '<br/>';
echo '<br/>';
```

This returned the same mysqli object but slightly different. Here is the output.

```
u2l14a8l846b5le667ibnio0p5
```

$db_link object

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(161) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(14) "5.5.41-MariaDB" ["server_version"]=> int(50541) ["stat"]=> string(149) "Uptime: 2341490 Threads: 2 Questions: 166712462 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 1668302 Flush tables: 2 Open tables: 400 Queries per second avg: 71.199" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(2583258) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }
```

$$link object.

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(14) "5.5.41-MariaDB" ["server_version"]=> int(50541) ["stat"]=> string(149) "Uptime: 2341490 Threads: 2 Questions: 166712462 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 1668302 Flush tables: 2 Open tables: 400 Queries per second avg: 71.199" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(2583258) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }
```

I have tried switching the variables around to see if it truly was an issue with the dynamic variable but it seems the latter variable always outputs an object with affected rows -1 this might be another piece of info why the object dissapears of becomes unusable.

EDIT2:
Log with the errors being thrown by PHP

```
[01-Sep-2016 17:38:21 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/user/domains/domain/public_html/includes/functions/database.php on line 160
[01-Sep-2016 17:38:21 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/user/domains/domain/public_html/includes/functions/database.php on line 53
[01-Sep-2016 17:38:21 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/user/domains/domain/public_html/includes/functions/database.php on line 53
[01-Sep-2016 17:38:21 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/user/domains/domain/public_html/includes/functions/database.php on line 53
```

Errors are being thrown here because of a tep_db_query using tep_db_input to escape a key in the query. Hence the mysqli_real_escape_string that is being thrown first and then the others because the tep_db_input fails since the object 'dissapears'.

I have done a small test to see where exactly the object starts behaving weirdly. I modified the tep_db_input function to pass along numbers for debugging.

```
 function tep_db_input($string, $num = 0, $link = 'db_link') {
   global $$link;

   echo '<br/>';
   echo '<br/>';
   echo $num;
   echo '<br/>';

   echo $string;
   echo '<br/>';
   var_dump($db_link);
   echo '<br/>';
   echo '<br/>';
   var_dump($$link);
   echo '<br/>';
   echo '<br/>';

   return mysqli_real_escape_string($$link, $string);
}
```

This gave me the following results.

1
u2l14a8l846b5le667ibnio0p5

"Object 1 from previous test"

"Object 2 from previous test"

2
u2l14a8l846b5le667ibnio0p5
NULL <- This is where object 1 should be dumped

NULL <- This is where object 2 should be dumped

The code where this is being executed is as follows.

```
function _sess_read($key) {
    $value_query = tep_db_query("select value from " . TABLE_SESSIONS . " where sesskey = '" . tep_db_input($key, 1) . "' and expiry > '" . time() . "'");
    $value = tep_db_fetch_array($value_query);

    if (isset($value['value'])) {
        return $value['value'];
    }

    return '';
}

function _sess_write($key, $val) {
    global $SESS_LIFE;

    $expiry = time() + $SESS_LIFE;
    $value = $val;
    $check_query = tep_db_query("select count(*) as total from " . TABLE_SESSIONS . " where sesskey = '" . tep_db_input($key , 2) . "'");
    $check = tep_db_fetch_array($check_query);

    if ($check['total'] > 0) {
        return tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_SESSIONS . " set expiry = '" . tep_db_input($expiry) . "', value = '" . tep_db_input($value) . "' where sesskey = '" . tep_db_input($key) . "'");
    } else {
        return tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_SESSIONS . " values ('" . tep_db_input($key) . "', '" . tep_db_input($expiry) . "', '" . tep_db_input($value) . "')");
    }
}
```

These two are called in

```
session_set_save_handler('_sess_open', '_sess_close', '_sess_read', '_sess_write', '_sess_destroy', '_sess_gc');
```

Comment: why are you using 2x `$` signs here? `$$link`. And are you looking for a string or boolean match here `if (USE_PCONNECT == 'true')`? or are all these "intentional"?

Comment: Why are you using var-vars in the first place? They lead to this kind of ugly spaghetti/impossible-to-debug-code.

Comment: The `$$link` part is so that you can pass a name for the link variable in case you want multiple connections. It defaults to `$link = 'db_link'` which will become `$db_link`. And the match for the PCONNECT part is a string. The constant is defined in the config file for the web shop. `define('USE_PCONNECT', 'false');`

Comment: `if (USE_PCONNECT == 'false')` (or `=='true'`) should that ever happen, will not return boolean (true|false), it will look for a string equaling to (true or false).

Comment: You should also add an `else{...}` to the `if`'s and catch the real error. Error reporting will also be of use, and place your `if (USE_PCONNECT == 'true') {
      $server = 'p:' . $server;
    }`  below `$$link = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);`. The logic seems a bit off here. Check to see what happens when you change all `$$link` to just `$link`. If it works, then your wanting to use the variables variable way is failing somewhere in your config file, if you're using one. You still didn't respond to my mentioning about string/boolean check.

Comment: The `if (USE_PCONNECT == 'false')` is intentional. The `USE_PCONNECT` constant is defined as a string and will be matched for a string. The logic for that if statement is to concatenate a `p:` to the server string. Which I assume is needed for the other type of connection that is available in the webshop. I'll try to add in some more else part with error messages and see if anything pops up. Thanks for replying so far.

Comment: Use both http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to get the actual error(s), should there be any. You could also pop in  a comment for that answer given below. It doesn't look like they've seen your comment about that up there. You're not using any `mysql_*` leftover code also, are you? Just wondering. and check your paths also, includes/requires etc. It could be anything.

Comment: I have enabled error_reporting and it's being sent to a file. I will make a quick edit including the log and why it's being triggered that way.

Comment: seeing your edits and logs; it's unsure as to what your queries look like and how they're used. I don't know if anyone else has stayed as long as I have in the question so I'm out of ideas. If you're not passing the parameters to the functions, then that could be a reason. Other than that, I won't be of any further help on this one, sorry.

Comment: Alright I'll just let it sit for now hoping someone else can shed some light on this. I do very much appreciate the time you've taken to share your thoughts. Have a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom session save handlers are odd beasts. They have one foot in user land, where things behave as you would expect, and another foot in the ethereal world of the engine where dark magic resides. [To wit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php):

> [T]he write and close handlers are called after object destruction and therefore cannot use objects...

It's unclear to me exactly which session function is failing, but I suspect it is `_sess_write`. If you wire in a `debug_print_backtrace` at the top of `tep_db_connect` that will clarify.

Nevertheless, what I'd suggest doing is to put all your session functions in a class, then in that class' `open` method to get a link to your ADOdb and store it as a member variable, then register your session functions on an instance of that class. This will keep the link in the object and protected from the normal destruction of other global objects.

```
class CustomSaveHandler extends \SessionHandlerInterface {
    public function open($path, $name) {
        this->db = tep_db_connect(...);
    }

    public function read($id) {
        // MySQL database calls using $this->db; you'll have to refactor how
        // you're calling your tep_ functions
    }

    // etc.
}
session_set_save_handler(new CustomSaveHandler);
```

For reference, a [similar problem with custom session handlers and ADOdb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1453143/2908724).

Comment: It's a slight late update but this was the answer that helped me deduce the problem at hand. The sessions handler was really outdated and could not handle the mysqli object. The mysql connection worked fine since it was not an object. For this project we were shorthanded and did not have the time to rewrite most of the session functionality for this web shop. We ended up reverting to an older version of PHP to keep the shop up and running with risks included.

Answer (score 0):

You are using dynamic variable name

`$$link` is a variable of name `db_link` by default in `tep_db_connect`

`$db_link` does not exist so it returns `null`

Comment: @xXDarioXx Thanks for the reply, I have added a small test to see if this was the problem as an edit in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  function tep_db_connect($server = DB_SERVER, $username = DB_SERVER_USERNAME, $password = DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, $database = DB_DATABASE, $link = 'db_link') {
    global ${$link};

    if (USE_PCONNECT == 'true') {
      $server = 'p:' . $server;
    }

    ${$link} = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

    if ( !mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
      mysqli_set_charset(${$link}, 'utf8');
    }

    return ${$link};
  }



  function tep_db_input($string, $link = 'db_link') {
    global ${$link};

    return mysqli_real_escape_string(${$link}, $string);
  }
```